# Highlighting some texts in HTML with a backend process

Tags: python, html

First of all be patient with me. I know it's not the best way to pose this question but I try my best. I have some scripts that do this:

1- For one html file, get the readable part, tokenize it, do the part of speech tagging.

2- Use the model to recognize the named entities (person, location, organization)

Example of the text extracted form html: `Token1 Token2 Token3 Token4 ....`

So for each html file, I'm able to get the output in this format:

`Token1 B-LOC
Token2 I-LOC
Token3 NON
Token4 B-ORG
...`

This means that I have `Token1 Token2` as Location and `Token4` as Organization.

Now, what I want to do is to go back to the html file, highlight the occurrences of any Location/Person/Organization. By highlighting I mean for example changing the color of background of them to different colors. E.g., green for Person, red for Org and yellow for Loc.

What is the simplest/best way to do that? The only thing I thought of is to replace them in html by `<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">Token1 Token2</span>`. This has one drawback that my tokenization is not the same as how tokens are in the webpage. For example I might have `Token1Token2` in webpage but I can't find them by searching for `Token1 Token2`. This can be done also using some regular expression search. Is there any better was to do that?

Another question:

If I want to click on each distance or mouse over each instance and get a list of tokens that I already saved in the html file, how can I do that in html? Example I want my mouse to go over `Token1 Token2` and then I want a list shows up. Thanks a lot for your help. I truly appreciate.

Comment: you could generate a new html file with your format. use css classes for the styles of your tokens.

Comment: Probably need some specific input to work off of.

Comment: imagine a simple html page: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
  This is a page
  a simple page
</body>
</html>` now we want to change the background of `This is` (but it might not be exactly as this way in our output.

Comment: @1010 is there any example for that?

Comment: [Anthony Mifsud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14783567) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086786) saying "I found this website https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/colorizing-text-by-part-of-speech/ I hope this is what you're looking for."